# JSON Unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1

Tags: javascript, php, json

I get an error when I use a very simple JSON request.

Here's the php with the data:

```
    <?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$riqueza = array(
    "nombre" => "Agustin", "patrimonio" => "US$ 400,000,000") ;
echo json_encode($riqueza, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH | JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR | 
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX | JSON_ERROR_UTF8 | JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ;
?>
```

And here's JavaScript's code:

```
const AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest;
AJAX.open("GET", "database.php");
AJAX.onload = function() {
if (AJAX.status === 200 && AJAX.readyState === 4) {
    const miRiqueza = JSON.parse(this.responseText) ;
    document.getElementById("minombre").innerHTML = miRiqueza["nombre"] ;
    document.getElementById("mipatrimonio").innerHTML = miRiqueza["patrimonio"] ;
    
}

} 
AJAX.send() ;
```

Just for extra clarity, the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="interface.js" defer></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
<tr>
    <th id="minombre"> </th>
    <th id="mipatrimonio"> </th>
</tr>


    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Lots of people have the same error, but no answer seems convincing; there isn't any problem with the array typing that could cause an error, and even so I've placed a ton of constants on the php encoding to see if they catch any mistake. But the header and the GET request are recieved without the slightest problem: it seems like my parse is really stubborn and can't transform any data into an object. What is the problem? In case there isn't any obvious one, could I use $.ajax or jQuery to bypass the trouble? Would it make a difference?

Comment: Don't know how to do that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to send the content of `json_encode` in the HTTP response:

```
echo json_encode($riqueza);
```

Comment: Changed it, now I get JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data.

Comment: Take a look at the HTTP response with the F12 key, Network tab

Comment: The content type in the header is text/html, which is wrong: it should be application/json. And the status is 200, so no problem there.

Comment: And the body is valid JSON?